# why radmenu item click event is not firing?

Tags: telerik, radmenu

I am using Rad Menu in my website. and i am write code for menuitem click event.

when i checking with breakpoint, the item click event is not firing...

how to use Radmenu click event?

```
void menu_ItemClick(object sender, RadMenuEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item != null)
            {
               response.redirect("Myhomepage.aspx");

            }
        }
```

i used above code for item click event.. But it is not working.. any one knows???

Comment: what about the client side ,can u post a test case sample

Answer (score 0):

```
 <telerik:RadMenu ID="RadMenu1" CssClass="mainMenu" runat="server"  OnItemClick="RadMenu1_ItemClick"  ShowToggleHandle="true" >
       <Items>

            <telerik:RadMenuItem IsSeparator="true" />
            <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Products" >
                 <GroupSettings Width="200px" />
                 <Items>
                      <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Chairs" Value="1"  EnableImageSprite="true" CssClass="icon-chair"></telerik:RadMenuItem>
                      <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Sofas" Value="2" EnableImageSprite="true" CssClass="icon-sofa"></telerik:RadMenuItem>

                 </Items>
            </telerik:RadMenuItem>
            <telerik:RadMenuItem IsSeparator="true" />
            <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Stores" runat="server" Value="3">


            </telerik:RadMenuItem>
            <telerik:RadMenuItem IsSeparator="true" />
            <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="About" Value="4" />
       </Items>
  </telerik:RadMenu>
```

and code behind

```
 protected void RadMenu1_ItemClick(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadMenuEventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("You clicked: " + e.Item.Value);  
          string url= e.Item.Value;
            switch (url)
            {
                case "1":
                    Response.Redirect("");
                    break;
                case "2":
                    break;


            }
        }
```